WHERE and LIKE not finding everything with JOIN
I'm trying to create a table which lists all the people with job titles that contain 'Professor' and their projects.
I can get a return with the 'Professor and Chair', plus 'Associate Professor', with the JOIN, and without the JOIN all three together (Professor and Chair, Professor, Associate Professor.  But not all three with the JOIN.
I'm wondering if I need to reorder my code? I'm currently learning.
I've tried variations of Professor, %Professor% etc after AND and it still doesn't work.
With this I get a return of all three
SELECT
   sl.fullname AS 'FULL NAME', 
   sl.jobtitle AS 'JOB TITLE'
FROM staff_list AS sl
WHERE sl.jobtitle LIKE '%Professor%';

With this I only get Professor and Chair, and Associate Professor
SELECT
    sl.fullname AS 'FULL NAME', 
    sl.jobtitle AS 'JOB TITLE', 
    p.project_name AS 'PROJECT NAME'
WHERE staff_list AS sl
RIGHT JOIN projects AS p
ON sl.staff_id = p.staff_lead
WHERE sl.jobtitle LIKE '%Professor%';


Convert to a Left Join

You probably do not have a professor leading a project, but without sample data it is impossible to tell. Changing the join to left join could give you the expected outcome.

@Shadow of course I have. Otherwise it wouldn’t show up as having a project at all without the join. I’ll try changing to a left join.

It would show up without the join as youu have such people on your staff list. They just do not lead projects.

RIGHT JOIN will lists projects that don't have a professor (although the WHERE clause will then filter them out). LEFT JOIN will list professors that don't lead any projects.

Add a minimal reproducible example (ie table structure and example data)

Your second query will only show project leads, so if your "professor" isn't project lead, he won't show up in the result.
